# Assertion Error in Android Studio when trying to compile the working project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

While I was trying to build my working project in the updated Android Studio (0.3.6), I got the below error message. It works fine when I build via CLI.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.compiler.AndroidGradleBuildProcessParametersProvider.getVMArguments(AndroidGradleBuildProcessParametersProvider.java:101)
at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.launchBuildProcess(BuildManager.java:921)
at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager.access$1900(BuildManager.java:121)
at com.intellij.compiler.server.BuildManager$11$2.run(BuildManager.java:666)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
```

I already opened the issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62422).

However, it only happens to the existing project. Android Studio can build newly created projects.

I am confuse whether this is a bug of Android Studio or is there any setting I need to change to my existing project?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Here is a better solution so you do not have to import the project again.

Go to: `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` and select `Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 35):

Just remove .idea files from project. And import project again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Or update The SDK Build Tools, in Android SDK.

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

Invalidate caches

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

When I upgraded to android studio 4.2.1 then getting this kind of error and after searching on SO I found solution some where.

I run following command in **android studio terminal** when getting this error:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```