# Android Studio: Drag and drop is giving Throwable Assertion failed

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

After updating Android Studio to version 2.3 the drag and drop isn't changing the code position. Neither in `java` files nor in `xml`. After drag and drop code disappears and `Throwable: Assertion failed` is received in `Event log`

Tried

- Invalidate/Restart
- removing `.idea` and re-importing project
- changing the theme
- Changing `Appearance` - Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only

Referred
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892479/drag-drop-feature-in-android-studio-not-working) and
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063532/assertion-error-in-android-studio-when-trying-to-compile-the-working-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug and got fixed in the recently released version.

Update **Android studio** to **2.3.1**

drag and drop works as expected. Loved it. :)

*Coding is time consuming without shortcuts.*

Answer (score 0):

I too am experiencing this same issue after upgrading to Android Studio 2.3, where a selected block of code simply vanishes after dragging and dropping. I too get the Event Log entry: `Throwable: Assertion failed...`

I have posted a Bug Report to Google via the IDE bug reporting form previously on this issue, but have not seen any resolution to date.

Sorry to just be posting a "Me too" without any additional contributing evidence or helpful suggestions, but this is the first posting I have found where anyone else has experienced this same issue. Hopefully it will get addressed soon.